# Ubuntu 12.04 apt-get installs older version of software

Tags: 12.04, apt, versions

I'm using a software called vcftools which is present in Ubuntu repositories. When I `sudo apt-get install vcftools` in my Ubuntu 14.04, I get an up-to-date version (v0.1.11), whereas when I do the same on an Ubuntu 12.04 server, I get a really old version (v0.1.7) of the software.
Is there a way to get a newer version of vcftools on Ubuntu 12.04 using apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you manage to locate a PPA that has more up-to-date versions in it for 12.04 (my cursory check did not find any such PPA). The reason for this is most likely that the dependencies are different in 14.04 (more up-to-date); it is also possible that the package maintainer simply isn't bothering to build packages for older versions of Ubuntu.

If you greatly desire to run v0.1.11 on Ubuntu 12.04, you can try downloading and installing the source code. Upon initial inspection of the README.txt in the source code archive for 0.1.12b, it appears that the installation is simple and does not even involve compiling code. Simply download the package from the following link, extract the files, then pop open a terminal and follow the instructions for installation (found in README.txt):

[vcftools 0.1.12b download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcftools/files/latest/download?source=files)

Hope that has been helpful,

MG